# Viewing Japanese MBCS text while remote debugging from English Windows machine?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Trying to debug a MBCS application that has had the strings, dialogs, etc. localized for Japanese.  Seems to be a bug somewhere with a string getting truncated or something.

I am debugging from an English Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2013. Of course, since it is MBCS and not Unicode, when I view the strings, it is just gibberish. Probably, if it was unicode, then the strings would display in Japanese while remote debugging, but it's not, and it is not really an option.

So, is there any way to use some special encoding trick to view the string as Japanese on my English system.  I'm not going to set my local system for remote debugging to Japanese either.

So... basically looking for some kind of option to view the Japanese strings from the remote system as Japanese strings on my English system. Anybody else been down this road?

Comment: As far as I know, VS IDE still supports different language, you could install the language package set it under Tools->Options->Environment->International Settings in your VS. So you could view all VS windows in Japanese, is it the Environment you want to use?

Comment: Thanks Jack. If I get really desperate I might look into it. I was hoping there would be something like how you can view integers as hex or normal by changing the watch spec. I was hoping I could maybe set a watch spec for character set on a string. I can't read Japanese, but I can observe if something gets corrupted by splitting a byte pair on the wrong boundary which could happen with string manipulation operations. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have good solution for it, maybe you could custom the view using the extension:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx, I don't think we could change the language with this way, but we could change the type to view.

Comment: Interesting. I tried your first option. I still saw my strings in my code page. When I hit a random breakpoint, sometimes I would see text in Japanese, but when loading a Japanese string from a resource, I would only see as scrambled gibberish. I wrote a utility to load same string as Unicode and use WideStringToMultiByte with Japanese code page and the bytes were the same. So, weird. Our translators still have resources marked as English, but we don't load lang specific resouces from a DLL. We expect only one lang in a DLL.  Thanks for your suggestions @JackZhai-MSFT

Comment: Maybe the language package really has the specific supported scope/limitations, I mean that not all texts will be translated, if still no help for you, you could submit a feature request to the product team: : http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. The Visual Studio product team is listening to user voice there. You can send your idea there and people can vote.